# how to make a multi boot dvd for linux

Tags: linux

Is it possible to make a single bootable dvd with multiple linux distros in it? we should be able to select which os to boot by a menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several tutorials for this:

http://www.justlinux.com/forum/showthread.php?t=150078

http://pcquest.ciol.com/content/enterprise/2005/105070101.asp